# Flutter - Riverpod: How to read a value from provider only once

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a `UserNotifier` that has an `user` object as `state`, this object has some properties including a list of user's favorite topics ids. I have another `TopicsAsyncNotifier` that has a list of `topic` objects as `state`, however, this list must be created based on user's favorite topics ids, so in the `build` method of the `TopicsNotifierProvider` i first have to load the Topics from repository, then i must get the `userNotifier` instance to read the user topics ids and finally use the topics list and the user topics ids to create a new `Topic` object with an adittional property which indicates if the topic is present in the favorite user topics, a kind of `isSelected, isFavorite` flag. Let me show for better understanding.

```dart
class FollowedTopicsNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<List<FollowableTopic>> {
  @override
  FutureOr<List<FollowableTopic>> build() async {
    final topics = await ref.watch(topicsRepository).fetchTopics();

    final user = ref.read(userNotifier);
  
    final followedTopics = topics.map(
      (topic) => FollowableTopic(
        topic: topic,
        isFollowed: user.followedTopics.contains(topic.id)
      )
    ).toList();

    return followedTopics;
  }

  void updateTopics(String topicId, bool isSelected) {
    ... // logic to update state
  }
}
```

I just need the `build` method to be executed when the `TopicsAsyncNotifier` is initialized, when the user adds a new topic to favorites, i will update the topics list with `updateTopics` method. So my question is the following: The docs says it is bad practice to use `ref.read` in `build` method but if i use `ref.watch` or `ref.watch(provider.select)` to retrieve the list of user topics ids, when i add a new topic to the user list, the `build` method of `TopicsAsyncNotifier` will be called again, and i don't want that, because this loads again the initial topics and i already have them loaded in the state, so how could i read the value from `UserNotifier` only once to initialize the `TopicsAsyncNotifier` without `ref.watch` and `ref.watch(provider.select)`? I thought about using a ProviderScope to `override` the `TopicsAsyncNotifier` and pass the initial user topics ids in his constructor, but i don't know if that is a good approach.

I would appreciate any advice about how to achive the desired behaviour or maybe other approach to initialize a provider with other provider data without suscribe to changes (without ref.watch).

Thank you very munch!

Comment: The build should be run only once.  Are you lietting it autodispose perhaps?

Comment: No what i mean is that i need to read the current value from UserNotifier to initialize the state of TopicNotifier, in riverpod docs says it is a bad practice to use `ref.read` in `build` but if i read the value of the UserNotifier with `ref.watch` any change in UserNotifier state will call the TopicsNotifier `build` method again and i dont want that, because i only  want to read the value of UserNotifier once in the first TopicNotifier `build` method, witouth subscribe to UserNotifier changes, for that reason i must use `ref.read` instead `ref.watch` but the docs says it is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points that you can try to rethink:

1. Make a layer of cached data `TopicsNotifier`. This will allow you to fetch `fetchTopics` once in its `build` method and then return them each time. Then it will look like this:

```dart
class FollowedTopicsNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<List<FollowableTopic>> {
  @override
  FutureOr<List<FollowableTopic>> build() async {
    final topics = ref.watch(topicsNotifierProvider);

    final user = ref.watch(userNotifier); // better use `userNotifier.select`
  
    final followedTopics = topics. ... // handle AsyncValue here
  }
}
```

2. `final user = ref.read(userNotifier);` - you need to use `ref.watch(userNotifier)` or `ref.watch(userNotifier.select)` here,because your `FollowedTopicsNotifier` clearly and logically depends on data from `userNotifier`, which will obviously change, so you can't just read it once. This will break your program.

Comment: Ohh i see , I hadn't thought about that, i must rethink my structure, thanks for your help it helps me a lot!

Comment: do you know how i can make the same thing with Flutter Bloc ? in Flutter Bloc is a bad practice pass another bloc in constructor to listen the changes. they recommend the use of BlocListener to communicate two blocs, however when FollowedTopicsBloc is initialized i will need the topics and the user ids to create the initial state, so i don't know if maybe i must pass this values in constructor or which could be a better approach

Comment: You can try passing not blocks, but specific values ​​on which the current block depends. All this is implemented through the `...Proxy` provider. I think it's worth creating a separate question about this)